# Boot using UEFI - no way to change grapics mode used in GRUB

Tags: boot, graphics, uefi, bios, grub-efi

If i set my BIOS/UEFI to boot in legacy mode, grub shows up in standard 80x25 VGA text mode, which is fast and usable. If i set it to UEFI, it's hard coded to use a very slow driver for my laptop (lenovo c340) screen's native resolution. (1920x1080) ...slow as in, when it draws the very very small text, and rectangle border across the screen, i can see the cursor flashing and moving around, and it takes several seconds to draw the whole screen. This makes navigating the boot menu sluggish and cumbersome. This is especially annoying when i often need to reboot between runtime kernel (for music/audio stuff) and generic one, which -at least for now- i'm forced to use so virtualbox won't crash the whole OS.

Regardless what i put in my /etc/default/grub, then try to run update-grub, reinstall grub and so on, the boot loader still uses this extremely slow 1920x1080 graphics mode. Some live-discs/usb's also have problems booting in UEFI on this computer, so it might be a hardware or firmware issue.

Comment: What OS/release are you asking about?